# Is Postman Chrome Extension marked for deprecation? (Seeking company rep answer)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, postman

I've seen conflicting and stale information regarding whether Postman Chrome Extension is marked for deprecation or not. Could someone with direct knowledge address this question?

I need to know if I need to request that my work replace the extension with the native Windows app or not. Does the company intend to keep feature parity?

What's the difference between the Postman plugin and the extension? (since they are different)

Comment: All chrome apps are [deprecated](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) except on ChromeOS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the place to ask for company rep responses

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome version of Postman is not using the same runtime for execution of requests & test scripts. It is recommended to transit to the native client. Especially when you plan to use Postman collections with the CLI client Newman.

You can read a blog post of the company on this topic here: [Blog post on Chrome Extension vs. native app](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/08/23/using-the-postman-chrome-app-implications-from-the-recent-google-announcement/)

> We're encouraging Postman Chrome users to transition to the the Mac or Windows app when convenient, and to the Linux app when available, by heading to https://www.getpostman.com/apps and downloading the correct app. Going forward, we will be watching to see how Chrome OS app development proceeds, to make sure we provide the right tools for our community.